# Getting "fatal: 'path' does not appear to be a git repository" when pushing to Google Cloud instance

Tags: ssh, git, google-cloud-platform

I am in a Git repository:

```
$ cd /Users/me/dev/example
$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
$ pwd
/Users/me/dev/example
```

I ran these:

```
gcloud compute config-ssh
ssh example.us-west2-a.project
```

I even installed git on the remote instance:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install git
```

I added the remote like this:

```
git remote add google example.us-west2-a.project:$(pwd)
```

But when I `git push google master`, I get this:

```
fatal: '/Users/me/dev/example' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

What is going wrong, how do I git push to my google instance without first creating the repo manually on the instance?

Answer (score 0):

> how do I git push to my google instance without first creating the repo manually on the instance?

You don't. With the standard Git tools, it always needs to be created first (using `git init --bare`).

(Also, usually Linux home directories are kept at `/home`, not at `/Users`, so auto-creation wouldn't have worked in your case anyway.)

You can however find the "push to create" feature [in Gitea](https://github.com/go-gitea/gitea/pull/8419) and possibly also in GitLab, if you're willing to use either of those.

Comment: How does heroku work then? Don't I just do `git push heroku master`? Or are they upon `heroku create` creating a git repo on their server?

Comment: Can you show the commands that I should run on both local and remote machines?

Comment: Heroku runs heavily customized server software, so they might pre-create the repo on 'heroku create' (I would expect) or they might have made customizations like Gitea and GitLab did to allow auto-creating.