# Getting "fatal: this operation must be run in a work tree" after initializing a remote Git repo

Tags: ssh, git

I am super familiar with using Git *on GitHub*, but I am not at all familiar with git pushing to a custom machine instance.

I just figured out how to initialize a remote repo like [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1572242/getting-fatal-path-does-not-appear-to-be-a-git-repository-when-pushing-to-g), last step being that I need to create a `git init --bar` "placeholder" thing on the remote server, under `~/project.git`.

Then I went ahead and did this locally:

```
git remote add google example.us-west2-a.project:project.git
git push google master
```

And got the famous:

```
Enumerating objects: 4, done.
Counting objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 433 bytes | 216.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 4 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To example.us-west2-a.project:project.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```

Now, when I `cd project.git` on the remote machine, I notice it's similar to the `.git` folder inside my local project. And if I try to `git status`, I get the message:

```
fatal: this operation must be run in a work tree
```

So what do I do? I want to do a `git push` locally to push the *contents* of my git repo to my remote server, but I don't see any contents. How do I get and use the contents on the remote server? This way, I can then `cd project` on the remote server, and do `node server` to test out  my node app. Later on I can do a git post-push hook or something, like Heroku does, to deploy a new version of the app.